# Python open a link into links

Tags: python, urllib2

Hello I would like to reuse the output links for open a new link into the output website. With the RSS Feed I actualize the links. I need to process all output links. With which code this is possible?

```
import urllib2
import re

htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/tops/index.rss')
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = '<guid>(.+?)</guid>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
links = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
downloadlinks = ''
for i, link in enumerate(links):
    if i == 0:
        downloadlinks += link
    else:
        downloadlinks += ' ' + link

print (downloadlinks)
```

The Output is:

```
http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/leute/jennifer-lopez-singt-beim-geburtstag-von-turkmenistans-praesident-a-908601.html
http://www.spiegel.de/sport/sonst/tony-martin-setzt-tour-de-france-trotz-sturz-fort-a-908600.html
http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/ecuador-schiebt-verantwortung-fuer-snowden-auf-russland-a-908595.html
http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/wetter-temperaturrekorde-im-westen-der-usa-a-908593.html http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/polizei-raeumt-camp-hungerstreikender-fluechtinge-in-muenchen-a-908592.html
...
```

An other Example:

```
import urllib2
import re

htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.kino.de/rss/neu-im-kino/')
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = '<link>(.+?)</link>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
links = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
downloadlinks = ''
for i, link in enumerate(links):
    if i == 0:
        downloadlinks += link
    else:
        downloadlinks += ' ' + link

print (downloadlinks)

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    --------------------------'

htmlfile_2 = urllib2.urlopen(downloadlinks)
htmltext_2 = htmlfile_2.read()
regex_2 = '<meta itemprop="contentURL" content="(.+?)" />'
pattern_2 = re.compile(regex_2)
links_2 = re.findall(pattern_2,htmltext_2)
downloadlinks_2 = ''
for i, link in enumerate(links_2):
    if i == 0:
        downloadlinks_2 += link
    else:
        downloadlinks_2 += ' ' + link

print (downloadlinks_2)
```

The Output is:

```
http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/the-deep/130585
http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/englisch-fuer-anfaenger/145880
http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/the-grandmaster/147546 
http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/jets-helden-der-luefte/148993
http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/laurence-anyways/144027
http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/modest-reception-die-macht-des-geldes/142819
http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/papadopoulos-und-soehne/145922
http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/seitengaenge/132599
http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/a-silent-rockumentary/149048
http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/world-war-z/120130
```

I would like to have this:

```
htmlfile_2 = urllib2.urlopen(http://www.kino.de/kinofilm/the-deep/130585)
```

Than the Output is:

```
http://flashvideo.kino.de/video/clipfile/627/000551627.mp4
```

Comment: Do you want to open the links that you are printing?

Comment: Open them and then save their contents or do what with them?

Comment: Yes I want to open the links and open a link into the link/ website. For example: Open into this link: http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/leute/jennifer-lopez-singt-beim-geburtstag-von-turkmenistans-praesident-a-908601.html this link http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/leute/jennifer-lopez-singt-beim-geburtstag-von-turkmenistans-praesident-a-908601-druck.html

Comment: So as I understand it, you want to open each link's print version and then save the results?

Comment: This is only an example. I want to edit with urllib2 the links into the links from the rss feed.

Comment: You cannot edit the links with urllib2, do you want to recreate the RSS feed with the updated links? Take one link, and update your question with an example of what you want to do.

Comment: use `for` loop with `urlopen` to open links one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate through each of the original links, printing out all of the children links.

```
import urllib2
import re

htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.kino.de/rss/neu-im-kino/')
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = '<link>(.+?)</link>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
links = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

print( ' '.join(links) ) # or print( '\n'.join(links) )


for link in links:
    htmlfile_2 = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    htmltext_2 = htmlfile_2.read()
    regex_2 = '<meta itemprop="contentURL" content="(.+?)" />'
    pattern_2 = re.compile(regex_2)
    links_2 = re.findall(pattern_2,htmltext_2)

    print( ' '.join(links_2) ) # or print( '\n'.join(links_2) )
```